# Reading nested archives with the zip:// wrapper

Tags: php, zip

I'd like to read nested archive files using the [zip:// wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php).

The archive looks like this:

```
outer-archive.zip > inner-archive.zip > file.xml
```

I tried the following:

```php
file_get_contents(
    'zip://zip:///path/to/outer-archive.zip#inner-archive.zip#file.xml'
);
```

But it doesn't work, probably because of the two `#`s.

**Is it possible to make this work?**

I'm trying to avoid extracting one of the archives to a temporary location. Another solution *not* involving the `zip://` wrapper (`ZipArchive`, ...) would also be accepted.

Comment: Theoretically: Yes. Practically: No. PHP builtins can't do this and, while someone _could_ write userland code to do this, it is quite esoteric.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález They can be nested. Example: `echo "Hello, world" > file.txt; gzip file.txt; bzip2 file.txt.gz; php -r "echo file_get_contents('compress.zlib://compress.bzip2://file.txt.gz.bz2');"`

Comment: I stand corrected. Thank you for the example.